# Batch - End of String Comparison with Symbols

Tags: string, batch-file, symbols, string-comparison

I am trying to do a comparison between the last 4 characters of a string in a variable to a string with symbols.
The string with symbols to compare to is "%1" (including quotations).
The string in the variable can have spaces, quotations, slashes, etc.
e.g.

> var="C:/something here/there" /abc "%1"

ex:

```
if substr(%var%,-4) neq '"%1"' ( echo %var% )
```

I have tried various forms, my latest looks something like the following:

```
if %var:~-4% neq """%%1""" echo %var%

if "%str:"=*%%str:"=#%" neq "*%%1*#%%1#" echo %var%
```

I thought I could figure it out after I got some help with the comparison to the string with symbols, but I am having trouble putting it all together...

Comment: `if "%var:~-4%" NEQ "%%1" echo %var%` should work; note that `var` must be defined for the substring expansion `:~-4` to work (can be checked with `if defined var`); a literal `%` is given as `%%`, so `%%1` will be replaced by `%1` literally; finally, putting `""` around both strings avoids many troubles (unless the strings contain `"` themselves);

Comment: Could you please list the symbols you have trouble with (beside `%`)? There are several characters in `cmd`/batch, that have some special meaning under some certain circumstances (some of them are: `%`, `"`, `&`, `^`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `(`, `)`, `!`,...);

Comment: @aschipfl I am mainly dealing with symbols included in filenames. %, ", &, /, \, (, ), ., and any other obvious ones are my main concerns

Comment: `"` is not allowed in file names, it is only used to _enclose_ file paths for them to be treated literally and not to be split on e. g. spaces; `\` and also `/` are path separators, so they cannot occur in file names; so `&`, `^`, `(`, `)`, `%` and `!` are allowed in file names; the best to avoid trouble with them is delayed expansion; the big problem is to _set_ a variable to a string containing such characters, because at some point you will need to state the string "literally"; I think there is no generally valid, all accompanying solution for that unfortunately...

Comment: @aschipfl ok thats fine, but i need to account for quotations AND symbols found in file names